# How do you program your discord bot to detect a word and only that word in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

To my knowledge, this question hasn't been asked yet so here goes.
In my code, I have my bots programmed to react to specific trigger words, and it works, but not without it's problems. 
The Problem I'm having is that my bot is responding to a small word, for example, 'Pen' and reacts to the word, but also reacts to a word like 'happen' because it has pen in it.

```
bot.on('message', message=>{
if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes('pen'.toLowerCase())) {
if (message.author.id === bot.user.id) return;
    message.channel.send(pen[Math.floor(Math.random() * pen.length)]);
}});
```

This is the code. And I should mention that I am very new to JavaScript

Is there something I can specifically do it to make it ONLY react to the word 'pen'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use word boundaries in regular expressions to only match a specific word, and not substrings of other words. Note the `i` flag at the end allows it to match both uppercase and lowercase "pen".

```regex
/\bpen\b/i
```

The expression above would match "pen" written as a word alone, but wouldn't match it inside "happened", for example. Here's how to use it in JavaScript:

```js
/\bpen\b/i.test('i have a pen') // true
/\bpen\b/i.test('that happened') // false
```

Finally, your code would look like this:

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
  if(/\bpen\b/i.test(message.content)) {
    if (message.author.id === bot.user.id) return;
      message.channel.send(pen[Math.floor(Math.random() * pen.length)]);
    }
  }
);
```

If you want to play around with the expression, I've [posted it to RegExr](https://regexr.com/556fu).

Comment: Or use `String.includes` instead.

Comment: @Seiyria note that they they don't want the bot to react to words like "happened", which includes "pen". Word boundaries guarantee it won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `message.content` equals to `pen`

```js
if(message.content.toLowerCase() === 'pen')
```

Comment: Ok, so, I tested it and realized that it only works for a single word. Is there a specific line a code that would work with only identifying 'pen' in a sentence?

Comment: Maybe a regex? Not too sure